# Topology (Basis)

Tags: general-topology

A basis for a topology is defined as the subcollection of the topology such that every member of the topology can be expressed as the union of members of that subcollection. But if the basis doesn't contain the empty set but since the topology must contain the empty set then how can the empty set (being a member of the topology) be expressed as the union of members of the basis? Please help me out.

Comment: What is the union of no members?

Comment: That would be empty, @Servaes, please explain your answer

Comment: This means that the empty set can be expressed as the union of members of the basis, by taking the union of *no* members.

Answer (score 3):

Two ways to look at this:
First, my book defines the topology $\mathcal{T}$ generated by basis $\mathcal{B}$ to have open sets that are either the empty set or a union of elements of $\mathcal{B}$. From here, the empty set gets included strictly from definition.
Secondly, and to address the comments, if $\mathcal{T}$ has open sets $\bigcup_{a \in A}U_a$, (where each $U_a \in \mathcal{B}$) then we can take $A= \emptyset$ to get $\emptyset \in \mathcal{T}$.

Comment: You are right thank you @Sloan